# How to implement UIAppearanceContainer protocol in an NSObject subclass?

Tags: ios, uikit, uiappearance

I have a custom popover controller class that is a subclass of `NSObject`. I want it to be usable in `+appearanceWhenContainedIn:`, just like `UIPopoverController`. But simply appending `UIAppearanceContainer` to its protocol conformance list does not work:

```
@interface WLPopoverController : NSObject <UIAppearanceContainer>
- (instancetype)initWithContentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
…
@end
```

The cause, I think, is that `UIKit` does not know that `WLPopoverController` is part of the appearance container hierarchy. For example:

```
UIUINavigationController *navController = …
WLPopoverController *popoverController = [[WLPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
…
```

`UIKit` does not think `navController.navigationBar` matches the partial ordering of `[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], [WLPopoverController class], nil]`.

What should I do to make it so?

Comment: You can't use the UIAppearance API on non-UIView subclasses unfortunately. Best bet is to either use your own theme class or expose the underlying view of your popover...